# How can I declare array, as a anonymous struct member (or workaround) in C?

Tags: c

I have a struct declared like this

```
typedef struct {
  volatile uint8_t B[2][32];                       
       uint8_t RESERVED_0[4032];
  volatile uint32_t W[2][32];                  
       uint8_t RESERVED_1[3840];
  volatile uint32_t DIR[2];                    
       uint8_t RESERVED_2[120];
  volatile uint32_t MASK[2];                   
       uint8_t RESERVED_3[120];
  volatile uint32_t PIN[2];                    
       uint8_t RESERVED_4[120];
  volatile uint32_t MPIN[2];                   
       uint8_t RESERVED_5[120];
  volatile uint32_t SET[2];                    
       uint8_t RESERVED_6[120];
  volatile  uint32_t CLR[2];                   
       uint8_t RESERVED_7[120];
  volatile  uint32_t NOT[2];                   
       uint8_t RESERVED_8[120];
  volatile  uint32_t DIRSET[2];                
       uint8_t RESERVED_9[120];
  volatile  uint32_t DIRCLR[2];                
       uint8_t RESERVED_10[120];
  volatile  uint32_t DIRNOT[2];                
} GPIO_Type;
```

Is there any way to declare reserved spaces above as anonymous?
Aka. not using RESERVED_1,RESERVED_2, etc for every not implemented space.

I know for example on bit fields, we can do that:

```
struct test {
   unsigned: 1;
   unsigned: 5;
   // etc

};
```

Thanks,

Comment: Use a union (maybe an unnamed one?)

Comment: how can I use a union, will not overlap my useful registers?

Answer (score 1):

You could use anonymous unions:

---

```
typedef struct {
union {
        volatile uint8_t B[2][32];
        uint8_t ALL_0[4096];
        };

union {
        volatile uint32_t W[2][32];
        uint8_t ALL_1[4096];
        };
union {
        volatile uint32_t DIR[2];
        uint8_t ALL_2[128];
        };
union {
        volatile uint32_t MASK[2];
        uint8_t ALL_3[128];
        };
union {
        volatile uint32_t PIN[2];
        uint8_t ALL_4[128];
        };
union {
        volatile uint32_t MPIN[2];
        uint8_t ALL_5[128];
        };
union {
        volatile uint32_t SET[2];
        uint8_t ALL_6[128];
        };
union {
        volatile  uint32_t CLR[2];
        uint8_t ALL_7[128];
        };
union {
        volatile  uint32_t NOT[2];
        uint8_t ALL_8[128];
        };
union {
        volatile  uint32_t DIRSET[2];
        uint8_t ALL_9[128];
        };
union {
        volatile  uint32_t DIRCLR[2];
        uint8_t ALL_10[128];
        };
union {
        volatile  uint32_t DIRNOT[2];
        };
} GPIO_Type;
```

Comment: hmm.. no, this is not correct. ALL_x will overlap with data. In addition, ALL_x means that I still have to declare each one with separate names which is exactly what I want to get rid of.

Comment: I was assuming that you will not be using the padding regions. (why would you?)